# why i can't run my Django project with : python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

I encountered an error:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\Youssef\\Documents\\Hello_Django\\import_data'
```

However, I do not have a file named `import_data`, and I am not using the path `C:\\Users\\Youssef\\Documents\\Hello_Django\\import_data`. This is where I had my previous project, which I have since deleted.

i tried this :     `python manage.py runserver`

i expect the localhost to my web app

Comment: Can you post the content of `manage.py`?

Comment: Are you importing `import_data` from anywhere in your code? Are there mentions of `import_data` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Make sure it's `import_data.py` (extension is `py`) or `__init__.py` exists in `import_data` folder. Also, you'll need to make sure your python path includes `C:\Users\Youssef\Documents\Hello_Django`